# Change Form content with drop down lis

Tags: forms, jsp

This is what I'm working on:

```
<form name="leave" method="post" action="lins.jsp" onSubmit="chk();">
<center>
<p>Leave Type: <select id="myl" name="Type">
    <option> </option>
    <option>Casual</option>
    <option>Extended</option>
    <option>Medical/Sick</option>
</select>    
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dt"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="edt"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subm" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clr" />
</center>
</form>    `
```

Is there any way to display an additional set of buttons(Basically to upload a file) when   Medical option is chosen (without directing to a fresh page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this by using JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showBtn(ele)
  {
     if($(ele).val() == "medical"){
         $("#uploadFile").show();
      }
     else{
         $("#uploadFile").hide();
      }
   }
</script>
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<form name="leave" method="post" action="lins.jsp" onSubmit="chk();">
<center>
    <p>Leave Type: <select id="myl" name="Type" onchange="showBtn(this)">
                      <option> </option>
                      <option value="casual">Casual</option>
                      <option value="extended">Extended</option>
                      <option value="medical">Medical/Sick</option>
                   </select>    
    <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dt"></p>
    <p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="edt"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subm" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clr" />
    <input type="file" value="Upload File" name="file" id="uploadFile" style="display: none;" />
</center>
</form>
```

Here i have given value to the options in dropdown, added upload file button in form but initially it is hidden. I have call function `showBtn(ele)` on `onChange` event of dropdown, in that function i have cheked that if value of selected option is `medical` than show button else hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You could show that using jquery hide/show() event
Create a button,

```
<button id="hideMe">Upload file</button>
```

And following jquery ,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hideMe").hide();
    var selVal=$('#my1').va();
    if(selVal=="Medical"){
    $("#hideMe").show();
    }
      return false;
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps !!